# External library dependency hierarchies

Tags: cmake

I am building a project that depends on a third party library that is composed of a fairly large numbers of libraries. The DAG of dependencies between these libraries is clearly defined so for example it might be the following where letters indicate libraries and arrows are dependencies

```
x -> a, b
y -> a, c
z -> x, b   // note I don't need to specify a here as it is implied by x
```

So what I really want is to be able to express this DAG in CMake and be able to expand dependencies without repetitions. So

```
Expand( y, z ) -> y, z, x, a, b, c    // Note only one a
```

I will spare you my attempts to do the expand function as I couldn't come up with anything elegant, I am not that good at CMake.

An extra feature would be to detect redundancy in the top level dependencies so

```
Expand( z, x )  // x not needed as z depends on it
```

Note CMake already does something like this for internal project library dependencies and uses it in thing like target_link_libraries but these are external so CMake does not know the external dependency tree.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from CMake documentation, `target_link_libraries` doesn't work with imported library as first argument. But you can easily develop function, which reads properties from dependent (imported) libraries, and fill corresponded properties for dependee (imported) library. So, resulted imported library can be used with `target_link_libraries` at the right side.

```
# _combine_targets_property(VAR PROP target1 target2 ...)
# Helper function: Collects @PROP properties (as lists) from @target1, @target2 ..,
# combines these lists into one and store into variable @VAR.
function(_combine_targets_property VAR PROP)
    set(values) # Resulted list
    foreach(t ${ARGN})
        get_property(v TARGET ${t} PROPERTY ${PROP})
        list(APPEND values ${v})
    endforeach()
    set(${VAR} ${values} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

# imported_link_libraries(t_dest target1 target2 ...)
# Make imported library target @t_dest effectively linked with @target1, @target2 ...
function(imported_link_libraries t_dest)
    # IMPORTED_LOCATION's and INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES's from dependencies
    # should be appended to target's INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES.
    get_property(v1 TARGET ${t_dest} PROPERTY INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES)
    _combine_targets_property(v2 IMPORTED_LOCATION ${ARGN})
    _combine_targets_property(v3 INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES ${ARGN})
    set(v ${v1} ${v2} ${v3})
    list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES v)
    set_property(TARGET ${t_dest} PROPERTY INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES ${v})

    # INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES' from dependencies
    # should be appended to corresponded target's property.
    get_property(v1 TARGET ${t_dest} PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
    _combine_targets_property(v2 INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${ARGN})
    set(v ${v1} ${v2})
    list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES v)
    set_property(TARGET ${t_dest} PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${v})

    # Process other interface properties if needed. E.g., INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.
    ...
endfunction()
```

Usage example:

```
add_library(a IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(a IMPORTED_LOCATION <a_lib> INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES <a_include_dirs>)

add_library(b IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(b IMPORTED_LOCATION <b_lib> INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES <b_include_dirs>)

add_library(x IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(x IMPORTED_LOCATION <x_lib> INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES <x_include_dirs>)

imported_link_libraries(x a b)

add_executable(my_exec ...)
target_link_libraries(my_exec x)
```

Note, that imported *target names* are not tracked in the dependencies, this is similar to `target_link_libraries()` behaviour. Also redudancy is not detected (but duplicates are removed automatically). Both these features are not natural for CMake, but you can implement them if you want.